# Refactoring duplication with two different return types in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Say I have these lines of code in all of my controllers:

```
public View ControllerClass() {
    // ...
    // some code in controller
    SomeClass someClass;
    try {
        someClass = Util.getParam(
                context.getEncryptedParam(), soemthignElse.getSomething());
    } catch (SomeException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
        return viewBuilderFactory.view1.view();
    } catch (AnotherException ex) {
        return viewBuilderFactory.view2.view();
    } catch (etc ...) {}

    // use someClass
    // ...
    return viewBuilderFactory.view3.view(); 
}
```

In this case I'd have two different return types (`void` and `view`) if I want to move the duplication to its own method. What'd be a good approach here?

Comment: What's wrong with returning `null` for the empty case?  Maybe a more concrete example would help us understand the question.

Comment: @JimGarrison well I don't think that'd be a good approach to `null` check the return type every time I'm using this function

Comment: As I said, without a more concrete example it's hard to tell what the correct answer would be.  If a method truly needs to have an empty return as well as non-empty return, then returning `null` is a valid way to accomplish this.  However, the need to have both is code-smell.  You might need to encapsulate the return in an object that contains a result code for the exception cases.  We cannot tell from the skeleton you have provided.

Comment: @JimGarrison just added some missing parts. also did you mean `null` instead of `void`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is best restructured as follows:

```
public View ControllerClass() {
    ViewBuilderFactoryView viewBuilderFactoryView;
    try {
        SomeClass someClass = Util.getParam(
            context.getEncryptedParam(), soemthignElse.getSomething());
        // use someClass
        // ...
        viewBuilderFactoryView = viewBuilderFactory.view3; 
    } catch (SomeException ex) {
        log.error(ex);
        viewBuilderFactoryView = viewBuilderFactory.view1;
    } catch (AnotherException ex) {
        viewBuilderFactoryView = viewBuilderFactory.view2;
    } catch (etc ...) {}

    return viewBuilderFactoryView.view(); 
}
```

In other words, if you successfully obtain a `SomeClass`, go ahead and use it, and afterwards return some `View`.  If you do not successfully obtain a `SomeClass`, then just return some `View`.

Comment: well you can't really "refactor" the code this way, can you? the only duplication in the code is the parts I mentioned and the `// use someClass` is not a part of it really.